# Create custom note environment with tcolorbox

Tags: environments, paragraphs, tcolorbox

I just stumbled upon the `tcolorbox` package but can't seem to find my way through its extensive [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a custom environment to add short notes into a body of text. The enclosed paragraph should start with the word '**Note:**' in bold and appear next to a vertical line flush with the left margin of the surrounding text, like so:

[image]

So far, I've been using the `mdframed` package for this but I am starting to get annoyed by its frequent warnings of the sort

> You got a bad break because the last box will be empty you have to
>   change it manually by changing the text, the space or something else.

Here's the code I've been using so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    innerrightmargin=0pt
]{siderule}
\newenvironment{note}%
    {\begin{siderule}\textbf{Note:}}
    {\end{siderule}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{note}
    Here comes a useful note for demonstration. Let's add enough text to break the line, just to be sure the vertical line extends with the text.
\end{note}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I hope someone can help streamline it and make it more robust with `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Yes, the `tcolorbox` manual is overwhelming

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such a box is quite easy with the `borderline` options, which draw vertical bars (or other stuff)

Since the `note` environment should be versatile, there might be an optional argument that sets other options if needed, see the second (ugly!) example of the `note` environment.

The vertical etc. spacings before/after and inside of the box might be change using `left=...` etc. and `before skip={}` etc. keys.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw, % better frame drawing
  borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{red}, % straight vertical line at the left edge
  sharp corners, % No rounded corners
  boxrule=0pt, % no real frame,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  coltitle={black},  % Black colour for title
  title={Note:\ },  % Fixed title
  attach title to upper, % Move the title into the box
  #1
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{note}
    Here comes a useful note for demonstration. Let's add enough text to break the line, just to be sure the vertical line extends with the text.
\end{note}

\begin{note}[borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{blue}, colback=yellow, drop shadow={red,opacity=0.6}]
    Here comes a useful note for demonstration. Let's add enough text to break the line, just to be sure the vertical line extends with the text.
\end{note}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more sophisticated usages of `borderline` etc. please have a look on [Reproduce a PDF table with colored vertical semi lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301876/reproduce-a-pdf-table-with-colored-vertical-semi-lines/301905#301905)

Here's a version in which the first line of the `note` box is aligned with the label of an enumerate environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw, % better frame drawing
  borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{black}, % straigh vertical line at the left edge
  sharp corners, % No rounded corners
  boxrule=0pt, % no real frame,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  coltitle={black},  % Black colour for title
  title={Note:\ },  % Fixed title
  attach title to upper, % Move the title into the box,
  right=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  baseline={\tcb@height-2\kvtcb@boxsep+\baselineskip-2\lineskip}, %%%% Needs more to be done for other setups
  #1
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{note}
    Here comes a useful note for demonstration. Let's add enough text to break the line, just to be sure the vertical line extends with the text.
\end{note}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{note}
    Here comes a useful note for demonstration. Let's add enough text to break the line, just to be sure the vertical line extends with the text.
\end{note}

\item \begin{note}
    Here comes a useful note for demonstration. Let's add enough text to break the line, just to be sure the vertical line extends with the text.
\end{note}

\end{enumerate}



\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just saw, that I missed the `Note: ` lead in

Comment: you could use a detached title for that?

Comment: @Naphaneal: I know ;-) Thanks anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I was about to ask about that. :) In any case, I've been doing some testing with this and have to say it works great! Way better than `mdframed`, as I had hoped. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remark: I also added the options `frame hidden`, `opacityfill=0` (from your comment [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287438/tcolorbox-without-background-color-transparent)), changed `borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{black}`, and set all sides except left to `0pt`, to reproduce my old environment exactly.

Comment: @Casimir: Yes, of course -- you define the settings ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer One thing I just noticed: When beginning the note right after an `\item` with no text in between, the item label is moved down vertically to align with the lower edge of the note. Do you of any way to make the item label align with the _top_ of the note?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37829/discussion-between-casimir-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just noticed that adding the keyword `breakable` to `note` overrides your baseline adjustment. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Casimir: `breakable` boxes have different height etc. settings and it's not clear how large the box will be. I am not sure there's an easy way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't quite see where the complication comes from. Whether or not the box brakes across a page does not affect the position of its upper edge, right? Shouldn't something like `box align=top` with the boxe's baseline lowered from the top by one `\baselineskip` still work?

Comment: @Casimir: I can't check this right now. It was difficult enough to align it already in the non breakable version (the alignment requirement was an extra issue anyway, not in your question)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for all this work, I really appreciated  your detailed answer. I have implemented your main answer (the preamble part) to produce these type of "notes". The problem is that when you print the document in paper, (with a HQ laser colour printer) the grey boxes are hardly seen in that grey background. Therefore, I would like to increase the grey background to make it more darker. I have tried adding `opacityback=10,` just after `title={Note:\ }`, but this does not work. Is there a way to make the grey background, more intense, darker? Thanks for your more than useful help

Comment: @DavidC. Thanks for your really appreciating comments -- it's happens very rarely to get such a positive feedback in the last time. Well, the background colour is controlled by the `colback` option, i.e. try something like `colback={white!70!black}` as an option to your `tcolorbox` definition. The larger the number (70 here), the brighter the 'gray' will be. Since you're using a colour laser printer you can try any other colour of course as well.